# Sending parameter to excel web access charts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, excel-services

I have some pivot charts displayed using excel web access, all of the charts have some filters, I would like to create a common filters to interact with excel web access charts.

Is there a way I can pass parameter or develop a connected excel web access charts...